# "#" not included while sending call (i.e. for mobile phone recharging) In android phone

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to make recharge process just by entering the recharge number and add up *401* at the beginning and # at last eg: *401*12387263736748#  . but call goes like: *401*12387263736748 
without "#" included.

```
    RechargeRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            RechargeCode = "*401*"
                    + RechargeCodeView.getText().toString()+"#";
            Intent RechargeingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                    .parse("tel:"+RechargeCode));
            try {

                startActivity(RechargeingIntent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot make call",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace "#" with Uri.encode("#") or "%23". But I will not recommend this, as this can cause some security issues.